# Cocoon link_to_remove_association remove only for view but not in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cocoon-gem

`link_to_remove_association` works for view but doesn't not delete in the database. Not sure what's wrong in my code. I can add and update totally fine.

Parameters:

```
"todo_list" => {
    "name" => "Stuff to do",
    "todo_tasks_attributes" => {
        "0" => {
            "_destroy" => "1",
            "name" => "1",
            "completed" => "0",
            "due" => "",
            "id"=>"3"
        },
        "1" => {
            "_destroy" => "false",
            "name" => "2",
            "completed" => "0",
            "due" => "",
            "id" => "4"
        },
        "2" => {
            "_destroy" => "false",
            "name" => "3",
            "completed" => "1",
            "due" => "",
            "id" => "5"
        },
        "3" => {
            "_destroy" => "false",
            "name"=>"4",
            "completed" => "0",
            "due" => "",
            "id" => "6"
        }
    }
},
"commit" => "Update Todo list", "id" => "2" }
```

In my log I get:

> Unpermitted parameter: :_destroy
>   Unpermitted parameter: :_destroy
>   Unpermitted parameter: :_destroy
>   Unpermitted parameter: :_destroy

This is my TodoList controller

```rb
class TodoListsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_todo_list, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /todo_lists
  # GET /todo_lists.json
  def index
    @todo_lists = TodoList.all
  end

  # GET /todo_lists/1
  # GET /todo_lists/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /todo_lists/new
  def new
    @todo_list = TodoList.new

  end

  # GET /todo_lists/1/edit
  def edit

  end

  # POST /todo_lists
  # POST /todo_lists.json
  def create
    @todo_list = TodoList.new(todo_list_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @todo_list.save
        format.html { redirect_to @todo_list, notice: 'Todo list was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @todo_list }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @todo_list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /todo_lists/1
  # PATCH/PUT /todo_lists/1.json
  def update
    if @todo_list.update(todo_list_params)
      redirect_to edit_todo_list_path(@todo_list), notice: 'Todo list was successfully updated.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  # DELETE /todo_lists/1
  # DELETE /todo_lists/1.json
  def destroy
    @todo_list.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to todo_lists_url, notice: 'Todo list was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_todo_list
      @todo_list = TodoList.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def todo_list_params
     # params.require(:todo_list).permit(:name, todo_tasks_attributes: [:id, :_destory, :todo_list_id, :name, :completed, :due])
      params
      .require(:todo_list)
      .permit(:name, todo_tasks_attributes: TodoTask.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym).push(:_destory))
    end


end
```

TodoList model

```rb
class TodoList < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :todo_tasks, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :todo_tasks,
                                 allow_destroy: true, 
                                 reject_if: proc { |att| att['name'].blank? }

end
```

todotask model

```rb
class TodoTask < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :todo_list, optional: true
end
```

_form

```rb
<%= simple_form_for(@todo_list) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :name %>
  </div>

  <table class='table'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
         <th></th>
        <th>Task Name</th>
        <th>Completed</th>
        <th>Due</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class='todo_tasks'>
      <%= f.simple_fields_for :todo_tasks do |builder| %>
        <%= render 'todo_task_fields', f: builder %>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
    <div class="links">
      <%= link_to_add_association('Add Task', f, :todo_tasks, class: 'btn btn-primary', data: { association_insertion_node: '.todo_tasks', association_insertion_method: :append } ) %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

_todo_task_fields

```rb
<tr class="nested-fields">
      <td>

        <%= link_to_remove_association  "remove task", f, class: 'btn btn-default btn-xs' %>
      </td>
  <td><%= f.input :name, label: false %></td>
  <td><%= f.input :completed, label: false %></td>
  <td><%= f.input :due, label: false, as: :string %></td>

</tr>
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! What params are being sent when you try to remove the TodoTask? Can you check your Rails logs or network tab on your browser and edit your question with the params shown?

Comment: Anecdotal: dynamically whitelisting attributes is a bad idea. Example: if you add in `user_id` as an attribute, anyone could overwrite the user_id and you'd be left wondering why. For that reason, it's best to just write them out.

Comment: @JoshBrody I have added my parameters and I realized I was getting Unpermitted parameter: :_destroy,  oh I will note for that and change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sily me... I had a spelling mistake on my params
:_destory -> :_destroy.

Problem solved